# The delarray package can't run the code

Tags: math-mode

Please, help me. I am a novice in LaTeX, and start learning A Guide to LATEX and Electronic Publishing Fourth edition Helmut Kopka & Patrick W. Daly. The question is — why using the code on page 108 with The delarray package.

```
\begin{array}[{cc}] a & b \\ c & d \end{array}
```

this code doesn’t work?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\include{setup} % other packages 
\setlength{\parindent}{1.2cm}
%%\usepackage{showframe} %% 
\RequirePackage{array}[1994/02/03]
\usepackage{delarray,colortbl}

\begin{document}
\spacing{1.25}
\newcommand{\doublerule}[1][.4pt]{%
  \noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[.7ex]{\linewidth}{#1}}%
  \rule[.3ex]{\linewidth}{#1}}
  
\begin{center}
{\Large \textbf{Tables}}
\end{center}
\doublerule

\vspace{.5cm}

$\begin{array}({cc}) a & b \\ c & d \end{array}$
\vspace{1.5cm} %well done

$[X,Y]=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & 0\\0 & -1
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$ %well done

\vspace{1.5cm}

\begin{array}[{cc}] a & b \\ c & d \end{array} %not works

$\begin{array}[{cc}] a & b \\ c & d \end{array}$ %not works


\end{document}
```

Where I did a mistake???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `array` looks for an optional argument, so it shouldn't find `[` for the delimiter.

Either you specify the optional argument or use `\lbrack`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{delarray}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}[c][{cc}] a & b \\ c & d \end{array}$
\quad
$\begin{array}\lbrack{cc}\rbrack a & b \\ c & d \end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excuse me once more, but why in the Guide book… was made so-called “aborted code”? I am learning  at the moment and I simply repeat some codes and see the results. Was it just  a mistake? Because  just with ( ) brackets this code works properly without extra [c] in code. I am very confused.

Comment: @Gennady_F I don't have Kopka and Daly. Maybe they didn't test the code… Anyway, `\begin{array}({cc)` works because `(` follows. With `[` `array` tries to scan the optional argument and eventually fails.